# VB import Text file into Excel\VB

Tags: vb.net, windows, excel

I have the following text file which I'm trying to automate into a line Graph in excel.. which logs every 5 minutes up until from 08:00 till 18:00 so there is quite a few rows

```
TIME      Rec-Created Rec-Deleted Rec-Updated Rec-read   Rec-wait   Committed    bi-    writes    Bi-reads     DB-Writes DB-READ     db-access  Checkpoints    Flushed
08:09:00          37           0          5      21276          0        1894          33           3         109          43       47691           1           0
08:14:00          49           0        144      20378          0        1225         143           0          88         192       53377           0           0
08:19:00          44           0        237      19902          0        1545         283           6         317         120       49668           2           0
08:24:00          51           0        129      12570          0         626         191           3         164          58       37811           1           0
08:29:00          61           0         49      14138          0         541          86           3         116          77       36836           1           0
08:34:00          59           0        144      58536          0        1438         209           3         143        3753      135427           1           0
08:39:00          85           0        178      28309          0        1822         209           6         209          80       70950           2           0
08:44:00          57           0        157      17940          0         554         132           3         170          92       47561           1           0
08:49:00         115           0        217      29961          0        1867         186           3         333         193       76057           1           0
08:54:00         111           0        225      23320          0         540         198           6         275         246       64138           2           0
08:59:00          41           0        152      15638          0         359         187           3         368         103       44558           1           0
```

I'm not too concerned about the Line graph part but more the trying to get the data into excel in the correct format.
I'm assuming I would need to use an array, but currently that is little advanced for me at the moment as Im still trying to get to grips VB and this is really my first venture into this world...(as you can see from my previous post)

any help or guidance would be appreciated..
(im studying the VB for Dummies and Visual Basic Fundamentals: Development for Absolute Beginners from the channel9 MSDN)

thanks in advance

Comment: This is a group where you should also be posting what you have tried.  Why do you need to use VB?  Why not just open the file in Excel directly?  You could record a VBA macro and work from there, also.

Comment: I didn't think that the Macro's recorded external files ? the reason for VB is that it will eventually (hopefully) form part of a bigger script, like my previous post.....Im out at the moment but will upload what i have tried once Im back....thanks for the response

Comment: The macro can record the method of parsing the text file, and translating it to a line graph.  That would help.  So far as VB is concerned, I can't help you.  I'm pretty knowledgeable with VBA, but not so much with VB.  With VBA you could select the external text file; open it; and create your line graph.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create  typed dataset, with all of your columns. Lets call it YourDataset.

Then read the file in and add rows to your table for each row in the file. Not fully functional but an outline of a solution.

```
 dim typedDataset = new YourDataset

 Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("file.txt")
        line = reader.ReadLine
        dim rowData = line.Split(" ")
            'add a new row to typed dataset based on data above
 End Using
```

That is how you would get your data into vb.net, it would be sitting in a table just like the excel table, at that point if you didn't care about excel you could use a graphing control like on this page. And see it with a datagrid view https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237(v=vs.140).aspx

But going to excel you would need to follow a guide like the one I have in the following link. You need to use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/669509/How-to-Export-Data-to-Excel-in-VB-NET